# Алгоритм проверки принадлежности одного множества другому

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных

Необходимо реализовать следующий алгоритм проверки: является ли множество из m целых чисел S подмножеством множества T размера n, m<=n, за O(n) в среднем случае.
Из идей использование хэш-таблицы в качестве контейнера, содержащего большее множество. Элементы множества, обладающего меньшей мощностью будем проверять на соответствие элементам хэш-таблицы. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможен ли такой подход, возможна ли более простая реализация?

Comment: Множества S и T - надо понимать, несортированные?

Comment: Можно хеш и по меньшему множеству и удалять из него элементы при переборе большего. Правда построение хеша или сортировка как то все равно выходит за O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "за **O(n)** в среднем случае" требует расшифровки.

Но если считать, что **m log m <= O(n)** и **n log m=O(n)**, то требованиям по быстродействию отвечает такой вариант:

1. Сортировка множества S.
2. Бинарный поиск элементов множества T по упорядоченному множеству S (совпавшие элементы множества S - метить!)
3. Если отмечены все элементы множества S, то оно суть подмножество T.